# Dual-boot Windows Server 2016 on a second hard drive after Manjaro

Tags: boot, multi-boot, uefi, gpt, refind

### Context and goal

I'm in an unusual situation.

I have two HDD. UEFI mode.

```
sda      8:0    0   1,8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   1,8T  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0  15,6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0 500,6M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 931,4G  0 part
```

**Note**: sdb will be formatted.

*My first* HDD is like this:

- **GPT** partition table
- **rEFInd** boot manager (EFI file is `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi` and the `/boot/efi` partition is `sda3` with flag `boot, esp`)
- **Manjaro** (ArchLinux based) as OS

I want to install Windows (Server 2016) on the second HDD in order to dual-boot.

How can I safely do that?

### Myth and legend

I read some people telling that each drive need only 1 ESP, some people telling to put 2 ESP on one drive and none on the other, some people telling to keep only 1 ESP on one drive and none on the other. The last point seems better for me but I may be wrong. So how many ESP should I keep and where? Have I a choice during windows install or Windows will automatically install one on his drive?

I also heard people telling to un-plug the Linux HDD, to be *safe*, some telling that the Linux drive is no more bootable because NVRAM was freed, some other telling that it works and some other telling that even with Linux drive plug back the computer automatically boot on Windows bypassing the boot manager.

What's true and what's false? I need to be safe.

### Answer

I finally manage to solve the issue (see answer).

Now my disk are like the following:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1,8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   1,8T  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0  15,6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0 500,6M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   450M  0 part (Name: Basic data partition, File system: NTFS, Label: Recovery, Flags: hidden, diag)
├─sdb2   8:18   0   100M  0 part (Name: EFI System partition, File system: fat32, Flags: boot, esp) 
├─sdb3   8:19   0    16M  0 part (Name: Microsoft reserved partition, Flags: msftres)
└─sdb4   8:20   0   931G  0 part (Name: Basic data partition, File system: NTFS, Flags: msftdata)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To safely dual-boot the two OS:

1. I unplugged the HDD1 (with Linux)
2. I prepared a USB boot media for Windows (with [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) but manual copy of the file on a NTFS partition works too, not FAT32 because one file is 4.6GB) from another computer
3. I pressed F2 on my motherboard (Asrock B350 Pro4) splash screen at startup to go to the *UEFI setup menu*
4. From there I checked that *Fast Boot* and *Secure Boot* are disabled
5. Then I booted from the UEFI of the USB boot media
6. Next I launched the 1st step of the Windows installation setup
7. I pressed `Left Shift + F10` to run `cmd.exe`
8. Next I used `diskpart` to convert the partition table of the 2nd disk (for Windows install) from MBR to GPT (I detailed steps below)
9. Then I canceled the installation of Windows and restarted apply changes
10. So I installed Windows this time
11. I shutdown the computer
12. I plugged back the HDD1 (with Linux)
13. At startup it automatically booted on Windows (may be due to my boot config or/and due to the SATA order)
14. So I restarted
15. I pressed F2 on my motherboard splash screen at startup to go to the *UEFI setup menu*
16. I changed the boot order of the different partitions and put the *rEFInd* first
17. I restarted
18. It booted on *rEFInd* and there was my 3 last entries + 1 new with Windows
19. I'm now able to boot either on Manjaro or Windows server

### Convert partition table from MBR to GPT with diskpart

```
diskpart
list disk (get the number of the disk to convert)
select disk X (replace X with the disk number)
detail disk (display information, check that you selected the right disk)
clean
convert gpt
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you found a solution, and that's great; but I want to explicitly answer some of your questions:

> I read some people telling that each drive need only 1 ESP, some people telling to put 2 ESP on one drive and none on the other, some people telling to keep only 1 ESP on one drive and none on the other. The last point seems better for me but I may be wrong. So how many ESP should I keep and where?

The EFI spec permits as many ESPs as you want, located wherever you want. Windows 7 (I don't know about later versions) tends to get confused if you put multiple ESPs on a single disk, though, so I'd advise against that. The ESP is meant to be shared across OSes, so it should be fine to do so, with the caveat that *because* it's shared, each OS might muck with the other's files. Of course, the same thing could happen even if you have separate ESPs. I recommend keeping a backup of your ESP(s) for this reason.

> Have I a choice during windows install or Windows will automatically install one on his drive?

I don't know offhand what Windows does in a multi-disk environment in terms of which ESP it uses, if each disk has its own ESP.

> I also heard people telling to un-plug the Linux HDD, to be safe, some telling that the Linux drive is no more bootable because NVRAM was freed,

*Some* (but not all) EFIs delete their NVRAM entries that point to non-existent files. Thus, unplugging a disk as you proposed (and did) *can* result in lost boot entries. These are easily recovered *if* you know how to do so and are prepared, but this loss can be quite challenging to most people, who lack the necessary skills. For this reason, I recommend against unplugging disks when installing new OSes; however, following my advice does increase the risk of losing the OS because of carelessness or a bug, so I also advise paying attention and having backups before proceeding with installing a new OS.

> some other telling that it works and some other telling that even with Linux drive plug back the computer automatically boot on Windows bypassing the boot manager.

Windows will set its own boot manager to be the default, so the boot-to-Windows phenomenon is quite common, even if you don't unplug the Linux disk. If the Linux entry has not been destroyed, you can adjust the boot order with the third-party Windows [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) tool.

Another recovery tool is rEFInd. If you put it on a USB flash drive or CD-R, that medium can serve as an emergency recovery tool -- plug it in, boot to it, and you can boot anything with a working boot loader on the disk, then use its tools (like `efibootmgr` in Linux) to add or re-order boot entries, or even to completely re-install a boot loader. The main caveat is Secure Boot -- the USB flash drive and CD-R images I provide on the [rEFInd downloads page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) don't support Secure Boot. Thus, you must either disable this feature or add Secure Boot support yourself, and that can be a pain.

Comment: I see that rEFInd installed on my HDD1's ESP automatically saw the ESP partition of HDD2 and so added a boot entry for Windows. Your tool is amazing. And thanks for answers.